# Prove that the cantor space is totally disconnected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

**Prove that the cantor space is totally disconnected.**

Let $(G,T)$ be the Cantor space and let $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_i,T_i)$ be homeomorphic to the Cantor space where $(A_i,T_i) = (\{0,2\}, T_{discrete})$.

I know that a product space is totally disconnected iff each of its factors are totally disconnected and totally disconnectedness is preserved through homeomorphisms.  Therefore $(G,T)$ is totally disconnected iff $(\{0,2\}, T_{discrete})$ is totally disconnected.

But $(\{0,2\}, T_{discrete})$ is not totally disconnected because the components $C_{\{0,2\}}(0)$ and $C_{\{0,2\}}(2) \neq $ a singleton set.

So wouldn't this imply that the Cantor space is not totally disconnected?

Comment: if you cant see that $\{0,2\}$ is disconnected, read your definitions again...

Comment: Totally disconnected set - Every non-empty connected subset is a singleton set.  Or $C_{X}(a) = \{a\}$ for each $a \in X$.

Connected set - The only subsets that are clopen are the null set and the set itself.

If $\{0,2\}$ was totally disconnected, then $C_{\{0,2\}}(0) $ = a singleton set.  But since it's discrete, $\{0,2\}$ contains $2$ and $\{2\}$ contains $2$ and their union = $\{0,2\}$.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: $C_{\{0,2\}}(0)\neq C_{\{0,2\}}(2)$. The next-to-last sentence in your comment isn't relevant to the definition.

Comment: I re-worded it for clarity.

Comment: I see now, $\{0,2\}$ is not connected because $\{0\}$ is clopen and $\{2\}$ is clopen, so $\{0\}$ and $\{2\}$ are connected subsets because they're both the only connected set that is a singleton set.